Task.Run with and without async delegate
I don't understand clearly difference between almost following Task asynchronous code execution.
Only difference is the async keyword as parameter.

Example - I think this code inside Task run will not run asynchronous
await Task.Run(async () =>
{
    var bytes = ImageManager.GetImage(path);
    if (bytes != null)
    {
        var _encoded = ImageManager.DecodeImage(bytes);
        var _sourceImage = ImageManager.GetSourceImage(_encoded);

        PreviewImage = _sourceImage;
    }
});


Example - This code behave as running asynchronous.
await Task.Run( () =>
{
    var bytes = ImageManager.GetImage(path);
    if (bytes != null)
    {
        var _encoded = ImageManager.DecodeImage(bytes);
        var _sourceImage = ImageManager.GetSourceImage(_encoded);

        PreviewImage = _sourceImage;
    }
});



I tried to do some research but I didn't clearly find exact answer about code sync/async code execution with given parameter async in Task.Run.
Is correct that Example 1. would run asynchronous if there would be any await task?

There are no awaits in either lambda, so they both run synchronously, and you should be getting a warning about the first one.

You can read in this article how and why the Task.Run understands async delegates.

While the Task.Run is the synchronous method, the task which is run by it performs asynchronously to the calling process.

@GSerg What does "synchronous" mean in your conception?

Synchronous means running on the same thread from start to finish, without any thread-switch or scheduling.

@TheodorZoulias "synchronous - happening, existing, or arising at precisely the same time". Synchronous process or tasks - process those have synchronous events. Compare vs Asynchrony https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchrony_(computer_programming). The process which calls Task.Run (the first) and the process called by Task.Run (the second) have no synchronous events. They are asynchronous. The cornerstone of asynchrony is the execution lock. Is any process able to lock another in the code above? No. The processes are asynchronous.

@Rotabor GSerg is talking about the code inside the lambda. He is talking about the async () => { } delegate. This delegate is marked with the async keyword, but there is no await inside it. So the C# compiler will issue the warning CS1998 "This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously.". You are right that the code runs asynchronously regarding the outer async context, but GSerg is talking about the inner async context.

@TheodorZoulias Sure, it looks like. But it follows us to misunderstanding. Since the delegate is the only content of the second task, there is nothing else inside Run() to determine it as synchronous to something. Such subtle feature may be unclear to OP.

@Rotabor the point is that both examples are doing exactly the same thing in exactly the same way. They use different overloads of the Task.Run method, but other than that there is no fundamental difference on how the program behaves between them. Personally I don't think that this question offers educational opportunities for the OP or anyone else. The OP has to study async/await systematically, instead of mindlessly adding an async in a delegate and then wondering why there is no difference in behavior. The answer is too convoluted to be of educational value.

The question suggested as duplicate is not an exact duplicate because the 2nd example doesn't return a Task directly. So I am casting a reopen vote. In case anyone finds a question that is a direct duplicate, please suggest. Most likely there are multiple, but finding one might be difficult.

async without await doesn't do anything so these two are identical
